# How can a Firefox XUL-addon prevent websites from stealing keypress events?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, keypress, dom-events, xul

I use a slightly hacked version of Firemacs, which is an "old" XUL-based addon for Firefox.  To watch for `keypress` events, the plugin creates an `<overlay>` and sources a script that uses:

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', handler, true);
```

However, websites may "steal" the events.  For instance, in SO's question textbox, I cannot type <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>, as it is shortwired to some formatting.  Similarly, Facebook steals a *lot* of keybindings, in particular <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>, which I use to paste from clipboard.

*Question:* How can I modify the addon so that it's always catching the keypress events first?
*Extra*:  How was this `<overlay>` overridden?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `keydown` and `keyup` and prevent those. A keypress is in response to `keydown` followed by `keyup`. You will notice that it fires 3rd. So if you prevent the key down from propagating with `e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault` in `window.addEventListener('keydown', func, true);` it should block it.

Comment: Aah, interesting!  Now, I do like the comfort of `keypress`, with its `event.which` that clearly spells out the key pressed.  But if I simply add a `keydown` listener to `stopPropagation`, then I cannot type anything in the browser.  Hence, is my only option to code everything in `keydown`, translating `keyCode`s to chars?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Michaël you can block the `keyup` also to prevent the `keypress` from triggering I think.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this.  Let me sum up: If I use `keypress`, Facebook (say) will not pass the event to my addon (I don't know *how*, in particular I don't know if they implement `keydown` or `keypress`).  Hence I have to do *something* with `keydown`.  If I altogether stop the `keydown` events with `stopPropagation` & `preventDefault` *all the time*, then I'm left with a useless browser. It thus seems to me that I have to implement the addon in `keydown`, fiddling with the erratic keycode to char conversion.  Are you saying that you see an alternative to that? Thanks very much!